# How to align multiple inputs inside <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I work on small `jquerymobile` project and I need to align three inputs inside single `<td>` but I don't know how to do it. I have found several examples to do it with `css` and classes inside input tags, I have tried to do something but it doesn't work, maybe because I call js function inside `class` or I'm missing something else.

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rzde9dsv/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <label for='name'> Name 1 </label>
                    <input type='text' width='20px' name='name' id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty1' width='20px' height='20px' value='Plus' class='plus' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty2' width='20px' height='20px' value='Minus' class='minus' />
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <label for='name'> Name 2 </label>
                    <input type='text' width='20px' name='name2'  id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty1' width='20px' height='20px' value='Plus' class='plus' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty2' width='20px' height='20px' value='Minus' class='minus' />
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='100px'>
                <span class='sidebyside'>
                    <label for='name'> Name 3 </label>
                    <input type='text' width='20px' name='name3'  id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty1' width='20px' height='20px' value='Plus' class='plus' />
                    <input type='button' id='qty2' width='20px' height='20px' value='Minus' class='minus' />                    
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS function:

```
$(function () {
    $('.plus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('span').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('span').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: *"I need to align three inputs inside single `<td>` but I don't know how to do it"* - How do you want to align them..?

Comment: Align them *how*? they are all aligned at the moment.

Comment: Unless that JavaScript affects the desired alignment, it's irrelevant to the question: as others have asked, how do you want these input elements aligned? In relation to what?

Comment: All things that I have tried before makes javascipt to stop working. Yes, they are already aligned, but not in the same line/row, they are arranged one under the other. @Darren gave me the answer with desired result. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, in that you don't say how you want to align them.

I am assuming you want *inline* for your third set, as you have a class `sidebyside`

*this is not finished, though will give you an idea*

So something you could do, which will need working on, though a start, is adding the following CSS to your page. This will force all first-children of the sidebyside to float to the left. Plus add some padding to the label (little dirty)

```
.sidebyside > *{ float:left; line-height:1.2} /* this line says, all immediate children of sidebyside, do this */
.sidebyside label {padding-top:15px;}
```

Also **removed the `width`** on your `td` that contains your `sidebyside` as this will prevent anything inside

Here is your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzde9dsv/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you need (td) for each input

**Demo** i did the first row for you

http://jsfiddle.net/46Lqyarx/

You need to change your function to get the closest **qty** from the **tr** instead of the **span** to make the plus and minus buttons do their job

```
 var $qty=$(this).closest('tr').find('.qty')


    <td>
        <span>
            <label for='naziv'> Name 1 </label>
            <input type='text' style='text-align: left' width='20px' name='name' align='left' id='id' class='qty' value='0' /></td>
        <td><input type='button' style='text-align: center' id='qty1' width='20px' height='20px' value='Plus' class='plus' /></td>
            <td><input type='button' style='text-align: right' id='qty2' width='20px' height='20px' value='Minus' class='minus' />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
```

**CSS** to move the buttons down a bit. you may need classes added if you have other types of buttons

```
.ui-btn {
margin-top: 23px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have already tried with on this way, but the main problem is in that javasript stops working.

Comment: let me check the code

Comment: '<td>' tag prevents javascript to work. Visualy is great, but all inputs must be inside single '<td>' to make it work. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Ok problem solved. because you have the (td) in there now you dont need to search from the (span) but from (tr). (var $qty=$(this).closest('tr').find('.qty')) -- http://jsfiddle.net/d5jh2ezc/

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it works great. I already got two working answers before your edit. Unfortunately I can't give positive vote for all of them, three at the moment including yours, and I would if I can. Anyways, thank you for your effort and help, I believe that'll be very useful in my future projects. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Don't worry man, it not the points that matter, a simple thank you will do. :)))

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Take the labels out of the  like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for='naziv'> Name 1 </label>
            <span>

                <input type='text' name='name' id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                <input type='button' value='Plus' class='plus' />
                <input type='button' value='Minus' class='minus' />
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for='naziv'> Name 2 </label>
            <span>

                <input type='text' name='name2'  id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                <input type='button' id='qty1' value='Plus' class='plus' />
                <input type='button' id='qty2' value='Minus' class='minus' />
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for='naziv'> Name 3 </label>
            <span class='sidebyside'>

                <input type='text' name='name3'  id='id' class='qty' value='0' />
                <input type='button' id='qty1'value='Plus' class='plus' />
                <input type='button' id='qty2' value='Minus' class='minus' />                    
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
td>label{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
td>span{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}
td>span>*{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Hvala Stevo, pokusacu i sa tvojim predlogom, za sada resenje koje je predlozio Darren daje ocekivani rezultat. Hvala jos jednom.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, also gives desired result. I'll probably use it in some of my future projects. Thank you for your time @Stevo.